# Show that the number of parity-preserving subsets of $n$ is equal to the number of odd-compositions of $n+2$

Tags: combinatorics

I have two sets (where $[n] = \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$):
$$
P_n = \{\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k\}\subseteq[n]\ |\ \alpha_i<\alpha_{i+1}\ \land\ \alpha_i\equiv i(\mod 2)\} \\
O_n = \{(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_k)\in(2\mathbb{N}-1)^k\ |\ c_1+\cdots+c_k = n\}
$$
where $k$ is a free variable (i.e. $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(3)$ are elements of $O_3$). I'm trying to find a bijection $f : P_n\to O_{n+2}$, which I'm inclined to believe there is.

I know that if we let $a_n = |P_n|$ and $b_n = |O_n|$, then $a_n$ and $b_n$ both satisfy $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ and $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$, with similar (but shifted) initial conditions sufficient to let us know that $a_n = F_{n+2}$ and $b_n = F_n$. Furthermore, I know that
$$
\left(1 - x - x^3 - x^5 - x^7 - \cdots\right)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 3x^4 + 5x^5 + 8x^6 + \cdots
$$
counts the number of compositions of $n$ with parts in $2\mathbb{N}-1$ (that is, the coefficient on $x^n$ is the number of compositions with $n$ odd parts). This is just the generating function for $b_n$.

I initially thought I could use the difference-partial sums bijection (which maps the set of all subsets of $[n]$ to the set of compositions of $n+1$):

$$
f(\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k\}) = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2-\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k-\alpha_{k-1},n+1-\alpha_k)
$$
but this only "sorta" works. I can't find a way to adapt it to a bijection from $P_n$ to $O_{n+2}$.

**How can I find a bijection from $P_n$ to $O_{n+2}$?**

Comment: In the definition of $P_n$, I assume we are ordering the elements $\alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \ldots < \alpha_k$. If we can label them in any way, the result doesn't work (try n=3).

Comment: That is correct, Ted, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're looking for happens to be equal to the number of compositions of $n+1$ with the constraint that all but the last part is odd (the last part can be any positive integer).

This can be shown using the difference-partial sum bijection that you described.

Observe the expression $$(\alpha_1, \alpha_2 - \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k - \alpha_{k-1}, n+1-\alpha_k)\\$$

The first $k$ parts are all odd, and the last part can be any positive integer. If you can find a bijection between this result, and all the odd compositions of n+2, you'll have proven what you want to prove.

Try to think about how you could change the last term to create a composition of $n+2$ with only odd parts. In particular, if the last part is even, add $1$ to the last part. If the last part is odd, you can add $1$ as an extra part to the given composition. Then you'll have a composition of $n+2$ with only odd parts.

Show that this mapping is bijective (which should be relatively straightforward), and you'll have your result.